How is this flip flop expressed algebraically?
How is the following picture expressed in logical symbols? I’m confused about the crossing wires on the outputs to inputs.

Ref:ref

The problem of trying to understand the circuit with boolean algebra is that with S=R=1 the premise Q always the complement of Q' will break. If both inputs return to 0 with a small time interval, the circuit may oscillate. To summarize, boolean algebra doesn't take 'time' into consideration.

The boolean expression you're looking for is:
\$ Q = \overline{R+\overline{Q}}\$
and
\$ \overline{Q} = \overline{S+Q}\$
Just remember the truth table for the NOR gate:
A | B | X
---------
0 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 | 0
1 | 1 | 0

So if either \$S\$ and/or \$R\$ are high, then its output will be zero that will be carried to the opposite NOR gate's input, thus potentially altering the state of the opposite output or keeping it the same. Drawing a timing diagram can help visualize what's going on. The final output of a latch isn't instantaneous.

For understanding this circuit, you should "open" the crossings wires.
You can then fill the Kmap (inputs are (R,S) and (q1,q2)) and outputs are Q1 and Q2.
At the end of transitions, (Q1,Q2) must be equal to (q1,q2) (outputs reentered as inputs) .
You can then write the equations of the outputs (Three terms).
You can see the two "stable" complementary outputs with (R,S)= (0,0).
The (R,S) = (1,1) is the case where outputs are not "complementary" and this combination "should" not be used.
You can follow the outputs states using this "transition" table.
Note that if you use "delays", only one "input" can change at one time ...
The swapping of (Q1,Q2) from (1,1) to (0,0) to (1,1) ... "can't" practically happen, although I have seen this with capacitors added ...

Made with microcap v12
The y.xxxx are the values of xxxx = ( _q1,_q2,R,S).

